# Why is the Zend Framework API documentation that poor?

Tags: api, zend-framework, documentation

Is it my browser that doesn't work with [their API online documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/)?

The structure of it seems to be very bad compared to the [Java API online documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) and the [Yii API online documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/).

I am new to Zend Framework, so I wonder, should it be like that?

Comment: Yep, hangs every one of my browsers. Some lightweight javascript, I assume. Makes me wonder about quality of PHP code driving the framework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in regards to a programming-related task.  Questions or concerns about documentation quality should be directed towards the authors/maintainers of that documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the API is nice, the only problem sometimes they don't give real meaning of arguments

After the API is maybe a bit behind some java examples, but I find the [reference guilde](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) quiet impressive and complete. You've got 900 pages describing every piece of the framework with short code snippet that's just wonderful.

Personally I use more often the reference guide then the API documentation.

Comment: API docs are generated from PHPDoc blocks... and if there were code examples and stuff there, than ZF would be like 200MBs mass of text. All important things are in reference guide. You can check API docs only for undocumented "new" functions...

Comment: Reference guide with errors like Quick Start. Then i need something to do i must use code tracking :(

Answer (score 3):

I've been digging into Zend Framework for about a month now. I'm starting to catch on but I have to agree with the initial comment. The API documentation, at least what is available, is atrocious. What is this Dojo stuff anyway? I would expect a proper, standardized API reference for something as extensive and powerful as the Zend Framework. For an experienced software engineer the reference manual is really introductory material. Once it is digested all that is really needed is a good API reference that clearly shows properties, methods, inheritance tree, with brief descriptions where necessary. Like Java, AS3, etc. I could have saved myself about two weeks of time had I had full access to the API. I don't get it, but I intend to persevere with ZF.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem is the reference guide simply lists through all the components and has a massive page telling very long-haul uses of each component with no sort of scope of where said code should appear in your work flow.

I believe it should be re-factored to be like [CakePHPs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/) documentation, where each page is targeted at getting a specific task done, like "Saving Your Data", "Deleting Data", "Validating Data" and so on.

Real life examples with context are a lot more useful then the Zend Docs where I tend to have to guess where certain variables (commonly `$db`) come from - and in full MVC cases, does't even apply.